# Prove $\frac{\cos(x)}{1 - \tan(x)} + \frac{\sin(x)}{1 - \cot(x)} = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am tasked with proving the this equality $$\frac{\cos(x)}{1 - \tan(x)} + \frac{\sin(x)}{1 - \cot(x)} = \sin(x) + \cos(x).$$
I've spent hours on it and no matter how much algebra I do, I can't figure it out. Can some one please help me?

Comment: Write $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/ \cos(x)$ etc and use $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: Please improve your format, and show your work

Comment: Many answers seem to skip over this, $LHS$ is not well defined at many points while $RHS$ is well defined for all real $x$.

Comment: HINT $$ \frac {c^2}{c-s} + \frac {s^2}{s-c} = \frac {c^2-s^2}{c-s} $$

Comment: @Narasimham I think so too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\tan(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x)=1/\cot(x)$ and
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{1 - \tan(x)}+ \frac{\sin(x)}{1 -\cot(x)}=
\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos(x) - \sin(x)}+ \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x) -\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x) -\cos(x)}.$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You said you spent hours on this problem, it is possible you get confused about all these trigonometric functions. One suggestion could be to replace $\cos(x)$ by $c$ and $\sin(x)$ by $s$.

If this $\quad\dfrac{c}{1-\frac sc}+\dfrac{s}{1-\frac cs}=\dfrac{c^2}{c-s}+\dfrac{s^2}{s-c}=\dfrac{c^2-s^2}{c-s}=\dfrac{(c-s)(c+s)}{c-s}=c+s$

is making more sense to you, even though it's just [Robert.Z's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2595565) answer written with simpler symbols, then go for this sort of reduction when you work with trigonometric formulas.

Myself for instance I always write $c^2+s^2=1$ instead of $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$, I find it easier to remember.

Comment: Nice you like my trig shortcut cut notation. Also I use $t$ for tangent. Maybe no harm done when using  with single independent variable.

Comment: @Narasimham this was ironic... You just wrote the same I did but 2h later.

Answer (score 0):

$1- cot(x)=\frac{ sin(x) -cos(x)}{sin(x)}$

$1- tan(x)=\frac{ cos(x) - sin(x)}{cos(x)}$

Then we have

$\frac{cos^2(x) }{ sin(x) -cos(x)}+\frac {sin^2(x)}{ sin(x) -cos(x)}$

$ =\frac{-cos^2(x) +sin^2(x)}{ sin(x) -cos(x)}$=$\frac{(sin(x)-cos(x))(sin(x)+cos(x))}{ sin(x) -cos(x)}$=$sin(x) +cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\tan(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cot(x)}-\sin(x)-\cos(x)=-\cos \left( x \right) \tan \left( x \right) \cot \left( x \right) -
\tan \left( x \right) \sin \left( x \right) \cot \left( x \right) +
\cos \left( x \right) \tan \left( x \right) +\sin \left( x \right) 
\cot \left( x \right) 
$$ and note that $$\tan(x)\cot(x)=1,\cos(x)\tan(x)=\sin(x),\sin(x)\cot(x)=\cos(x)$$